# svn/ssh question in windows

Tags: windows, svn, ssh

I am trying to do a command line svn update on my windows machine (to use in a batch file), and I want it to emulate what my settings are in the Tortoise SVN GUI.

In the tortoise settings, we have to specify the following in the SSH client...

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe -l usernamehere -pw mypassword -i C:\Users\Mike\Documents\myprivatekey.ppk
```

and I simply right click update...

does anyone know how I would use the svn.exe to emulate the above?  (using plink with a private key?)

If I am not clear on something please comment and I will work it out.

Best,
Mike

Answer (score 6):

[svn+ssh command line](http://agateau.wordpress.com/2007/07/03/windows-svnssh-and-the-subversion-command-line-client/)

Basically,

- Edit the file c:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Subversion\config
- Locate the section named [tunnels]
- Add the following line : ssh=c:/path/to/plink.exe -i c:/path/to/your/key.ppk

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get subversion to work with `plink`, so I used Git's SSH. Details on my wiki at http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/howtos/subversion/subversion_access_through_ssh_on_windows.